# Как правильно выбрать CMS под высоко-нагруженные проекты?

Tags: cms

Уже несколько дней думаю над тем как правильно выбрать CMS под высоко-нагруженные проекты? Так как я не могу раскрывать подробности проекта, то спрошу так - какую CMS Вы бы использовали если бы делали Хэшкод?

Comment: Однозначно Битрикс, хорошее соотношение по цене и качеству. Хорошая тех поддержка, большое сообщество, базовые инструменты по аналитике сайта с тех. стороны.

Comment: Однозначно не битрикс!

Особенно под HiLoad!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Высоконагруженные проекты и CMS - практически несовместимые условия.

Я бы выбрал какой-то framework из этих трёх - Zend 2, Yii или Symfony2.

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint, но это больше чем просто cms, платная и требует специальную настройку сервера

Comment: ужас этот ваш шарепоинт, а не цмс. в нормальных браузерах работает как попало.

Comment: Продукты microsoft заточены под IE.

Answer (score 2):

посмотрите как вариант cms Drupal

Comment: Разве подходит для высоконагруженных проектов?

Comment: whitehouse Ubuntu и тд написаны на Drupal. Очень гибкая cms